# How to install wso2 products on pure wso2 carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

My requirement is need to install (ESB,Application Server,Data Service Server,Api Manager,BAM) on pure wso2 carbon 4.2.0.

Is it possible to install all these products on Carbon?

I want to install multiple products on same carbon instance . I downloaded the P2_REPO from this site http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2 and tried feature installation using UI,but it is not allowing me.

Can anyone tell me the best possible way to do this. I want multiple products on same carbon

Your soon reply will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily install features through UI following this documentation, https://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Installing+Features+via+the+UI

It will be easy for you to go by product by product rather than selecting all feature group at once.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. How to install product wise in a single carbon rather than selecting group features?  I tried the feature installation using UI,but not all the features can install on Carbon, showing conflicting dependency. If we used all the products in a single Carbon,will it be scalable?

Comment: No installing all products in a single carbon instance is not at all commended and it won't scale at all. Create the p2 repo for carbon 4.2  as shown in the documentation and search with product name.For example to install ESB, search as "Enterprise Bus 4.8.1". In carbon 4.2 products are released as chunks and you many need to have those patches installed for products released in new chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. What i try to did is I downloaded the P2_REPO as per the documentation and tried to install ESB in wso2 carbon 4.2.0,but while installed and started the carbon,some configuration files are missing,showing in the console while starting the carbon. So can you recommend me the best approach,i want to use multiple products in Carbon 4.2.0(say ESB,ELB,IS,Application Server and Data Service Server),what is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download wso2 manually in direct wso website either deb or rpm package

a)check command: whereis wso2

b) move wso2 folder to /opt directory

2. /opt/wso2/wso2am/2.6.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml
   a)check and add the domain in gatewayendpoint
   b)https://xxxxxxxxxx

   ```
     disable comment line     below
   ```

http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}-->

3. /opt/wso2/wso2am/2.6.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml
   a) Add below line hostname
   uncomment www.wso2.org
   xxxxxxx

   xxxxxxxxxx
4. start with below command
   JAVA_HOME=/path/jdk1.8.0_192 /path/wso2am-2.6.0/bin/wso2server.sh &

Reference mutual ssl:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Mutual+SSL+Support+for+API+Gateway